# cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'Id'} is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I Have error when use to Service in one Action.

> cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'Id'} is already being tracked. When attaching existing entities
>    Consider using 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the conflicting key values

dbcontext code

```
 services.AddDbContext<DBDatacontext>(options =>
                 options.UseSqlServer(
                     Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
```

my repository

```
     IEnumerable<Post> Gets();
     bool Edit(Post model);


     public IEnumerable<Post> Gets()
    {
        return _db.Posts;
    }
     public bool Edit(Post model)
    {
        try
        {

            _db.Entry(model).State = EntityState.Modified;
            _db.SaveChanges();
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

and service

```
    public IEnumerable<PostAdminVm> Gets()
    {
        var model = _repository.Gets();
        return _mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Post>, IEnumerable<PostAdminVm>>(model);
    }
    public bool Edit(PostAdminVm model)
    {
        try
        {
            var post = _mapper.Map<PostAdminVm, Post>(model);
            post.UDateTime = DateTime.Now;
            if (_repository.Edit(post))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            return false;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

and use 2 method in controller

```
    public ActionResult edit(PostAdminVm model1)
    {
        url = _post.Gets().Count() + 1;
        if (_post.Edit(model1))
        {
           return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
    }
```

but i have error when use 2 interface in 1 action
cannot be tracked because another instance with the same key value for {'Id'} is already being tracked.

Comment: Fail to reproduce you issue , for the error , please try the suggested solution in [this thread](https://forums.asp.net/t/2150446.aspx?type+CreditCard+cannot+be+tracked+because+another+instance+with+the+same+key+value+for+Id+is+already+being+tracked+) which may be helpful.